# Custom OIDC login page - host on identity server or client application server?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, gluu

Most IDAM servers (Identity Server 4, Gluu, Cloud services) provide a way to host a login UI on the actually identity server. This login page can be customized so that it can be branded like your website. This works well for security flows so when you reach an authorization end-point you are redirected to your identityserver/login page.

**But can you host the login page on the client application instead?**

And if so:

1. Is this advisable?
2. Is this more/less secure than hosting the login UI on the Identity Server?
3. Would this break security flow standards like OIDC / Auth 2.0 authorization code flow?
4. Would this simply call an API to authenticate against? e.g. one that is hosted on the identity
   server. Some appear to support this, but this seems a bit old / insecure compared to existing security flows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not really: the point of (federated) Single Sign On (SSO) is that one can use a single credential to login across different domains without divulging that credential to every domain/application.

Users use those credentials in one place against one server only to a trusted party aka. the Identity Provider. The Identity Provider then creates a derived token that is consumed by the 3rd-party application because the latter trusts the former to do so.

In case all applications belong to the same domain as the Identity Provider, the argument above no longer holds, but not using SSO would still mean that you'd have to login to each application separately, one by one.